# Arranging text in Linux

Tags: linux, file, sorting, text, sed

Let's say I have a file "example.txt" with the below content

```
user@computer ~ » cat example.txt

Output will be like              "aws"
                                 "aws-ec2"
                                 "aws-reinvent-2016"
```

Now I want to rearrange the output like below:

```
"aws", "aws-ec2", "aws-reinvent-2016"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Hmm, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' ORS=', ' example.txt
```

`ORS=', '` set's the *output record separator* to `,`. `$1=$1` does not change anything in the line but still tells `awk` to reassemble the line using the new `ORS`. `1` will always evaluate to `true` and makes `awk` print the record.